# Is there any way to add authentication into an MS Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, authentication

I have an excel spreadsheet with sensitive data. Recently the spreadsheet was accidentally shared with a person outside my company. I want to know if the following is possible:
- Ideally we want the Excel to check if the user is a company employee when the spreadsheet is opened and only show content if the user is a company employee. If the user is not an employee then don't show content.

Is this something that is feasible? If so what options are there to implement this?

Comment: You could do this but it would be easily defeated with a few minutes of Googling.  At best you could hope to defend against casual viewing.

Comment: how would I go about doing that please?